# Automatically replace values

Tags: php, arrays, replace, associative-array

I have functions which return different predifined values:

```
    function a(){
      $value = 'mercedes';
      replacevalues($value);

    }
    function b(){
     $value =  'audi';
     replacevalues($value);
    }
    function c(){
      $value = 'bmw';
     replacevalues($value);
    }
```

Is there a function in PHP which will do something like this:

```
function replacevalues($value){
 switch($value){
   case 'mercedes': 
   echo $value = 'topA'
   break;
   case 'audi':
   echo 'topB'
   break 
//and so on
}
}
```

It would be nice if could define an array like this which i only have to iterate through (Or some php function that already exists)

```
$a = array('mercedes'=>'topA', 'audi' => 'topB');
```

So that I could expand the array or change the corresponding replacements.

Regards

Comment: `function replacevalues($value){ $a = ...; echo $a[$value];}`?!

Comment: @Riz do you find this question to be Unclear?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is: [array_search](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)

```
$array = array(0 => 'azul', 1 => 'rojo', 2 => 'verde', 3 => 'rojo');

$key = array_search('verde', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('rojo', $array);  // $key = 1;
```